# Return value even if an entry does not exist

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT shop_entrys.id, shop_images.path FROM shop_entrys,shop_images 
WHERE shop_entrys.id = shop_images.s_id AND 
shop_images.pos = 0 AND 
shop_entrys.category_id = 1 
ORDER BY shop_entrys.pos ASC
```

However, a row in *shop_entrys* might exist with no link to a row in *shop_images*. Thus, *... WHERE shop_entrys.id = shop_images.s_id ...* will not be met. In this case, I would still like to return a result. For example:

`shop_entrys.id      shop_images.path
      1                 "/img1.jpg"
     ...                   ...
      42                "not found"`

How should I change the above query to still return a result?

Comment: Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN with COALESCE to give a default value to the 2nd column

```
SELECT shop_entrys.id, COALESCE(shop_images.path, 'NOT FOUND' )
FROM shop_entrys
LEFT OUTER JOIN shop_images 
ON shop_entrys.id = shop_images.s_id AND shop_images.pos = 0 
WHERE shop_entrys.category_id = 1 
ORDER BY shop_entrys.pos ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE()` :

```
SELECT shop_entrys.id,
        COALESCE(shop_images.path,'NOT FOUND') 
FROM shop_entrys
LEFT JOIN shop_images 
 ON(shop_entrys.id = shop_images.s_id AND 
    shop_images.pos = 0)
WHERE shop_entrys.category_id = 1 
ORDER BY shop_entrys.pos
```

Please avoid using implicit join syntax(comma separated) as it is deprecated and messy and a lot of times leads to mistakes. Use **only** the proper syntax of a join!

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me why I should not use implicit join syntax? It is the way I learned it back in school.

Comment: Well, the reason is more visible and clear when joining multiple tables. Try understanding a query that joins 7 tables with implicit join syntax, takes for ever.. Another reason is the `LEFT JOIN` with implicit join syntax which makes it even more complicated and makes limitations(a table can be outer joined only to one table ETC) . @Bobface

Comment: @Bobface - a further issue which can cause problems when people mix implicit and explicit joins is that they have a different precedence.